# ASP.NET MVC Routing for different countries

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a website that will service a few different countries. When a user hits the site, I'll use an IP locator tool to determine which country they are from. All of the countries will speak English so the views rendered will be the same, however pricing will be different as well as a few other things.

The routing I would want is something like:

- mydomain.com/UK/Pricing
- mydomain.com/Australia/Pricing
- mydomain.com/UK/Features/SomeFeature
- mydomain.com/Australia/Features/SomeFeature

You get the idea...

Can anyone provide me with the routing I'll need in the global.asax?

I've tried the following, but I don't want to have to create views for every country:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Default", 
"{country}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
 new { country = "UK", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
 );
```

Comment: No, we can't provide you with it. But we can help you with the routing you've already tried.

Comment: You don't need views for every country. Using the route you specified, you'll be able to get the value of `country` and then load the resource in that language from your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route should be good enough, you simply need to add an argument to your Action methods to retrieve the country value:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id, string country) {
  // your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm WebForms you can also use

```
string country = Page.RouteData.Values["country"].ToString();
```

Not sure if this works for MVC too, but I would assume so.